# Can I use PrimeFaces and PrimeFaces mobile in commercial projects without paying for it?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

There is PrimeFaces Elite Downloads and
Community Downloads on the Prime faces website. Prime faces is under
Apache License Version 2.0, January 2004(http://www.apache.org/licenses/) , but there is commertial licence too for PrimeFfaces Elite(http://www.primefaces.org/elite/license.xhtml).
I am not sure that I can use  community version in commercial projects for free.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the [Primefaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) (FAQ)

> **Can I use PrimeFaces in a commercial software?**
>
> Yes, Apache V2 License is a commercial friendly library. PrimeFaces does not bundle any third
> party software that conflicts with Apache. Same goes for Elite Releases for ELITE and PRO users.